# Varnish Error in a particular link

Tags: caching, server, varnish, http-status-code-503

I have a website and I have installed varnish cache in it. all the links in the website are working properly but when I click on one particular link I am getting the **503 - internal server error Guru Meditation Varnish cache server**. I have checked the varnish log and following is the data that I have come across.

```
    0 CLI          - Rd ping
    0 CLI          - Wr 200 19 PONG 1472475843 1.0
   14 BackendOpen  b default 103.50.163.47 48726 103.50.163.47 8080
   14 BackendXID   b 1721110551
   14 TxRequest    b GET
   14 TxProtocol   b HTTP/1.1
   14 TxHeader     b Cache-Control: max-age=0
   14 TxHeader     b Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
   14 TxHeader     b User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
   14 TxHeader     b Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
   14 TxHeader     b Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
   14 TxHeader     b Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
   14 TxHeader     b Cookie: es_newssubscriber=1; __atuvc=22%7C34%2C3%7C35; external_no_cache=1; timezone=Asia/Kolkata; adminhtml=6hbq70dlnu19let4lbilqot6p2; __zlcmid=cCfmnyWxhnfBhk
   14 TxHeader     b X-Forwarded-For: 106.51.242.246
   14 TxHeader     b X-Varnish: 1721110551
   14 BackendClose b default
   12 SessionOpen  c 106.51.242.246 4262 :80
   12 ReqStart     c 106.51.242.246 4262 1721110551
   12 RxRequest    c GET
   12 RxProtocol   c HTTP/1.1
   12 RxHeader     c Connection: keep-alive
   12 RxHeader     c Cache-Control: max-age=0
   12 RxHeader     c Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
   12 RxHeader     c User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
   12 RxHeader     c Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
   12 RxHeader     c Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
   12 RxHeader     c Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
   12 RxHeader     c Cookie: es_newssubscriber=1; __atuvc=22%7C34%2C3%7C35; external_no_cache=1; timezone=Asia/Kolkata; adminhtml=6hbq70dlnu19let4lbilqot6p2; __zlcmid=cCfmnyWxhnfBhk
   12 VCL_call     c recv pass
   12 VCL_call     c hash
   12 VCL_return   c hash
   12 VCL_call     c pass pass
   12 Backend      c 14 default default
   12 FetchError   c http first read error: -1 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable)
   12 VCL_call     c error deliver
   12 VCL_call     c deliver deliver
   12 TxProtocol   c HTTP/1.1
   12 TxStatus     c 503
   12 TxResponse   c Service Unavailable
   12 TxHeader     c Server: Varnish
   12 TxHeader     c Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
   12 TxHeader     c Retry-After: 5
   12 TxHeader     c Content-Length: 419
   12 TxHeader     c Accept-Ranges: bytes
   12 TxHeader     c Date: Mon, 29 Aug 2016 13:04:04 GMT
   12 TxHeader     c X-Varnish: 1721110551
   12 TxHeader     c Age: 10
   12 TxHeader     c Via: 1.1 varnish
   12 TxHeader     c Connection: close
   12 Length       c 419
   12 ReqEnd       c 1721110551 1472475834.790129185 1472475844.790269613 0.000046730 10.000097513 0.000042915
   12 SessionClose c error
   12 StatSess     c 106.51.242.246 4262 10 1 1 0 1 0 258 419
```

Can anyone let me know how I can solve this error?

Comment: Looks like Varnish can not talk to your backend at 103.50.163.47 8080

Comment: @Ronald Hi, Ronald how can i solve this?

Comment: Ssh into the box running varnish and then try to curl 103.50.163.47:8080